# In Nginx, worker_rlimit_nofile is for the whole process or for each worker process?

Tags: nginx

worker_rlimit_nofile's description is as follows:

> Specifies the value for maximum file descriptors that can be opened by
>   this process.

'this process' means the whole process or each worker process?

It's quite confusing to me.

**Reference**:
http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule

Answer (score 1):

The directive `worker_rlimit_nofile` is set for each worker process separately.

*Full Example Configuration* from [nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/):

```
...
worker_processes 5;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
events {
  worker_connections 4096;
}
...
```

Comment: Why 8192? Should the limit not match the number of worker connections?

Comment: @HashimAziz When serving files nignx uses 1 file descriptor for the client connection and 1 file descriptor for the served file. When acting as a proxy, it uses 1 file descriptor for the connection to the client and 1 for the upstream. It can also use 1 more if a temp file is used to store the server’s response if it is too big for the buffer.